# Jquery select2 json data with optgroup and images

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using select2 with spring mvc. I got the data from my controller that I need to display here in terms of options. But I want them to be grouped as optgroup and also I want images to be appended in it which can be inserted manually as given below : -

```
 <optgroup label="group">
    <option value="imageName">value 1</option>
    <option value="imageName">value 1</option>
    </optgroup>
```

Where imageName is the name of image. I want to :
1)  Group options in json.
2)  Provide this image attribute in json so that select2 can form the data.

Here is the code :

```
$("#my-select").select2({
        data : [ {
            id : 0,
            text : 'enhancement'
        }, {
            id : 1,
            text : 'bug'
        }, {
            id : 2,
            text : 'duplicate'
        }, {
            id : 3,
            text : 'invalid'
        }, {
            id : 4,
            text : 'wontfix'
        } ]
    });
```

I am creating my json manually from my objects. So I can provide any data here. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Select2 maps data objects to `<option>` and `<optgroup>` tags using the following logic

---

A data object (what is returned in the list) that looks like

```json
{
  'id': 'value-here',
  'text': 'text-here'
}
```

Will be mapped to an `<option>` that looks like

```html
<option value="value-here">text-here</option>
```

---

A data object that looks like

```json
{
  'text': 'label-here',
  'children': [data_object, data_object]
}
```

Will be mapped into an `<optgroup>` that looks like

```html
<optgroup label="label-here">
  <!-- HTML for the `children` -->
</optgroup>
```

---

So the data object that you are looking to return is

```json
{
  'text': 'group',
  'children': [
    {
      'id': 'imageName',
      'text': 'value 1'
    },
    {
      'id': 'imageName',
      'text': 'value 1'
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is there also a property that maps to CSS class?