# Select2 optgroup group on JSON/Ajax format request

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, jquery-select2

Using Select2 with JSON/Ajax call, I am trying to create group like this :

```
<optgroup label="Property Reference">
     <option value="1">5742</option> 
     <option value="2">5788</option>
     <option value="3">5762</option>
     <option value="4">5711</option>
</optgroup>
```

The documentation for my issue [is not available](https://select2.github.io/options.html#what-should-the-results-returned-to-select2-look-like).

---

The format I managed to get to work :

```
{
    results: [
        {
            id: 'CA',
            text: 'California'
        },
        {
            id: 'CO',
            text: 'Colarado'
        ]
    }
}
```

But there is no group here.

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31452318/3265284), I tried the following format :

```
{
    "results": {
        "text": "Mountain Time Zone",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "CA",
                "text": "California"
            },
            {
                "id": "CO",
                "text": "Colorado"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and

```
{
    "results": {
        "Mountain Time Zone": [
            {
                "id": "CA",
                "text": "California"
            },
            {
                "id": "CO",
                "text": "Colorado"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and

```
{
    "Mountain Time Zone": [
        {
            "id": "CA",
            "text": "California"
        },
        {
            "id": "CO",
            "text": "Colorado"
        }
    ]
}
```

But none are working. Anyone know what the correct format is ?

You can test it here : https://jsfiddle.net/5am4zda6/2/

EDIT Solved: Damn... Forgot `[]`.
Correct format is :

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "text": "Mountain Time Zone",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "CA",
                    "text": "California"
                },
                {
                    "id": "CO",
                    "text": "Colarado"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It's not working on fiddle.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try like this:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "text": "Groupe 1",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "CA",
                    "text": "California"
                },
                {
                    "id": "CO",
                    "text": "Colarado"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "text": "Groupe 2",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "CA",
                    "text": "California"
                },
                {
                    "id": "CO",
                    "text": "Colarado"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I think you have forgot `[` juste after "results"

Answer (score 0):

i haven't tried this plugin before but after looking at the related question you've mentioned, try to change the *"result"* index by *"data"* something like this:

```
{
    "data" : {
        'text': 'Mountain Time Zone',
        'children': [
          {
            'id': 'CA',
            'text': 'California'
          },
          {
            'id': 'CO',
            'text': 'Colorado'
          }
        ]
    }
}
```

But it would be better if you could provide us a working jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it's not working either... I am trying to set up a jsfiddle.