# Select2 optgroup format using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-select2

I've got an ajax call that get dynamic data and places them in select2 as follow :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: '/api/?stuff='+c,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        // If select2 is already defined, we destroy it and rebuild it with the new data
        if(typeof $(".select2edit").data('select2') !== 'undefined') {
            $(".select2edit").select2('destroy').select2({ data: response, width: '100%', closeOnSelect: false });
        } else {
            $(".select2edit").select2({ data: response, width: '100%', closeOnSelect: false });
        }
    }
});
```

I create the response using PHP and then transform it to JSON before sending it :

```
$old_emplacement = '';
$results = array();
$i = -1;

while($array_campaign = tep_db_fetch_array($campaign)){
    if ($array_campaign['name'] != $old_emplacement) {
        $i++;
        $results['results'][$i]['text'] = $array_campaign['name'];
        $old_emplacement = $array_campaign['name'];
        $c = 0;
    }
    $results['results'][$i]['children'][$c]['id'] = $array_campaign['id'];
    $results['results'][$i]['children'][$c]['text'] = $array_campaign['c_name'];
    $c++;
}

$results['pagination']["more"] = true;
```

Thus resulting in the following JSON format :

```
{
  "results": [
    { 
      "text": "Name 1", 
      "children" : [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "text": "Text 1.1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "text": "Text 1.2"
        }
      ]
    },
    { 
      "text": "Name 2", 
      "children" : [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "text": "Text 2.1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "text": "Text 2.2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "paginate": {
    "more": true
  }
}
```

I get a `No results found.` when select2 initializes and loads. And I have no idea why. It's the correct format as far as the [documentation](https://select2.org/data-sources/formats#grouped-data) is saying and [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31452318/jquery-select2-json-data-with-optgroup-and-images) seem to confirm. Any ideas where could the problem be coming from?

It's also good to note that my select2 is inside a form which is inside a modal, and this is it's html :

```
<select name="xx[]" id="edit-xx" name='xx' class="form-control select2edit" multiple>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the format generated by my PHP code. I'm posting the result here for anyone trying to generate a select2 optgroup format using PHP and for my own reference :

```
$old_emplacement = '';

$results = array();
$i = -1;

while($array_campaign = tep_db_fetch_array($campaign)){
    if ($array_campaign['name'] != $old_emplacement) {
        $i++;
        $results[$i]['text'] = $array_campaign['name'];
        $old_emplacement = $array_campaign['name'];
        $c = 0;
    }
    $results[$i]['children'][$c]['id'] = $array_campaign['id'];
    $results[$i]['children'][$c]['text'] = $array_campaign['c_name'];
    if(in_array($array_campaign['id'], $campaigns_array)) {
        $results[$i]['children'][$c]['selected'] = true;
    }
    $c++;
}
```